# ngOptions creates empty dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a dropdown menu, but when it loads, I get an empty dropdown select box.

I am using the following html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in data.suggestions">
    <td>
        <select ng-model="i.selYears" ng-options="selYears for val in selYears"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

With this data:

```
[
    {
        "years": [1, 2, 5]
    },
    {
        "years": [1, 2, 5]
    },
    {
        "years": [1, 2, 5]
    }
]
```

Is there something wrong with my data structure, or is it the `ng-options`?

Here is what I would like the final output to look like:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="1">1 year</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">2 years</option>
            <option value="5">5 years</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="1">1 year</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">2 years</option>
            <option value="5">5 years</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="1">1 year</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">2 years</option>
            <option value="5">5 years</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What are you trying to get to show up in your list?

Comment: I would like the array of years to show in the dropdown

Comment: You no property called `selYears`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code should work

```
  <select ng-options="y.years as y.years for y in selYears" ></select>
```

assuming selYears is a property on $scope e.g.

```
 $scope.selYears = [
    {
        "years": [1, 2, 5]
    },
    {
        "years": [1, 2, 5]
    },
    {
        "years": [1, 2, 5]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to repeat over the object `selYears` at a controller scope level, rather than the `ng-repeat` level.

You should be doing something like the following to have a `ng-options` for each year in the `ng-repeat` item's child property of `years`

```
<select ng-model="i.value" ng-options="year for year in i.years"></select>
```

EDIT: Having data like this (and using the HTML above) will allow an initial value to be selected for each list.

```
[
  {
    "years": [1, 2, 5],
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "years": [1, 2, 5],
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "years": [1, 2, 5],
    "value": 5
  }
]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I am still getting an empty dropdown, and this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngOptions/iexp?p0=undefined&p1=undefined

Comment: The `ng-model` for each select list is `null`, so an empty option is created for each one. To initialize the value of each list, you can set the `ng-model` for each object in your list to whichever value you want selected by default.

Comment: Just made an edit adding an example of how you could go about doing that.

Answer (score 1):

**Html :**

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in data.suggestions">
    <td>
        <select ng-model="i.selYears" ng-options="year for year in i.years"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
        value : {{i.selYears}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

**JS :**

```
$scope.data = {
    "suggestions" : [
        {
            "years": [1, 2, 5],
        },
        {
            "years": [1, 2, 5],
        },
        {
            "years": [1, 2, 5],
        }
      ]
   };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ybwpfth/1/

Answer (score -1):

You must have to specify the field name which you want to display in the dropdown from your **json** data.

```
<select ng-model="i.years" ng-options="selYears in i.years"></select>
```